# How to highlight text like Android spell-checker?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

How do underline text in Android text fields, like the spell-checker does in this screen shot:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you got output for this? If you got please share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use Spannables.  Spannables are character sequences that incorporate style.  For this, use an UnderlineSpan

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to change the underline color? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533142/how-to-set-color-of-underlinespan

Comment: Wrap it in a ForegroundColorSpan.  Or it might be a BackgroundColorSpan, but its one of the two.

Comment: Wrap it? I don't understand. How do I apply two spans (UnderlineSpan and ForegroundColorSpan) to the same Spannable?

Comment: A Spannable can hold another Spannable.

Comment: Using ForegroundColorSpan applies the color to the text and underline. I want to only apply it to the underline, like in the screen cap above.